# Where or how to integrate pipeline into pre existing project repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

We have a product that is several years old. Its Git repository includes branches and/or tags for the version currently under development, the latest release, and previous releases. The latest release and the two previous releases continue to receive active support -- bug fixes and so on.

(In case it matters, the Git server is Bitbucket Cloud.)

We are migrating from Jenkins to Azure DevOps for our builds. The Azure Pipeline for our builds was developed using a fork of the project repository, and concentrating on the latest release. That is, the `pipeline` branch was a child of the `latest-release` branch.

Now we want to integrate the pipeline into the actual project repo, not a fork, and in such a way that it can be used to build the previous releases as well as the latest release. In addition, the pipeline will continue to be modified as well.

How do I organize my repository to integrate the Azure Pipeline (basically five .YML files), so that the pipeline can be used with branch `release_6_2_0`, and also with branch `release_6_1_0`, branch `release 6_0_0`, and branch `develop`?

Comment: Cherry-pick or otherwise merge the commits containing your pipeline work into the appropriate branches.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of, but I was worried that I was missing a more elegant solution. I guess that's the only way to add a pipeline to an existing project.